# What is in DNX 1.0.0-RC1-Update2

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

We were considering bumping some current ASP.Net Web Api 1.0.0-RC1-Update1 solutions to RC1-Update2...but not sure if there is a compelling reason to do so.  I can't find release notes for Update2 anywhere (perhaps I'm just missing them).  There is a release on GitHub for RC1-Update1, but not even a release tag is present for Update2. Can anybody point me to some information or the basic benefits if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dnx rc1 update2 has only one fix in it. The bug fixed was preventing `dnu wrap`-ed projects to work in VS if you didn't have VS 2013 installed

Edit: here's the fix https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/3376